# MySQL converting rows to number of columns pivot

Tags: mysql, pivot

I've got a query that displays the list of team leaders & their contact details and the people who report to them (subordinates). The team leader's details are displayed multiple times.

```
TeamLeader | PhotoLink | Cellphone | Email | Subordinate |
Joe        | joe.jpg | 0123 | joes@gmail.com |Mary |
Joe        | joe.jpg | 0123 | joes@gmail.com |Lilly |
Joe        | joe.jpg | 0123 | joes@gmail.com |Mark |
Joe        | joe.jpg | 0123 | joes@gmail.com |Simon |
```

I then manually copy this information into Word for a report so that the team leader's name & details are displayed once in the first row with 4 columns (photo link, name, cellphone number, email address) and the next rows the subordinates are split across 4 columns

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
Joe | joe.jpg | 0123 | joes@gmail.com |
Mary | Lilly | Mark | Simon |
Steve | steve.jpg | 4567 | stevem@gmail.com |
Jason | Agnus | Julie | |
```

Doing things this way manually takes ages and when there are changes to structure, I basically need to re-do the report each time which is time consuming.

Is there a way to create this type of data view dynamically that I can merely copy and paste it into Word instead of redoing the whole report each time from scratch?

If this view isn't possible then would it be possible to display the subordinates for the team leader ID specified in query?

For example, where teamleaderID = 1 then results are

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
Joe | joe.jpg | 0123 | joes@gmail.com |
Mary | Lilly | Mark | Simon |
```

For example, where teamleaderID = 2 then results are

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
Steve | steve.jpg | 4567 | stevem@gmail.com |
Jason | Agnus | Julie | |
```

I'm guessing a `GROUP_CONCAT` or `PIVOT` would do the trick but just not sure how to go about this.

Not sure if you can somehow use the record count with a CASE statement to put the 1st record in Col1, 2nd record in Col2, etc. But the CASE statement would need to be dynamic as you don't know for sure how many rows will be returned for each team leader.

Could you divide the record count by total number of rows to see which column to put it into (e.g. record count 1 / 4 = 0.25 then Col1, 2 / 4 = 0.5 then Col2, etc.)?

Comment: SQL shouldn't be used for presentation. And columns should always contain like values. You should have a PHP page (or something similar) handle the query and presentation. Then copy from that into Word.

Comment: Thanks Tony for the help with formatting and SQL. I had in fact thought of the PHP option but unfortunately I'm not too familiar with PHP so I'd have to skill myself up first before proceeding on that route. I thought that perhaps there might be an easier option first before tackling PHP. Got any quick PHP tutorials that may help me on my way?